# .NET8 Blazor App in Subroute via MapGroup

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

I have created a new Blazor Web App using .NET 8 Preview 7.
In the Program.cs I have only moved the app component via MapGroup() into a subroute. (*mySubPath*)

```cs
using BlazorApp1;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents();// Add Blazor/Razor services to the container.

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

var groupOne = app.MapGroup("/mySubPath"); // <-- new subpath 
groupOne.MapRazorComponents<App>();       // <-- map App.razor Cmp into /mySubPath/...

app.Run();
```

To make the example fly I have modified the App.razor as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

<!-- HERE -->
    <base href="/mySubPath/"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorApp1.styles.css"/>
    <HeadOutlet/>
</head>

<body>

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js" suppress-error="BL9992"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, the result is that the website can't resolve/find theier references.
I understand that the static css files are placed elsewhere. And I am able to fix this.
But I have no idea what to do to get the _framwork/blazor.web.js, the BlazorApp1.styles.css and the routing which is not working to work.

[image]

Have you perhaps had a similar problem or an idea for me what I can do here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you pls let us know you have blazor server or blazor wsam asp.net core hosted? And did you follow any tutorials for your reqirement?

Comment: Hi @TinyWang i use the new Blazor App (aka. Blazor United) wich is new in .NET8 and combine Server and WSAM. I try to figure out with docs from Microsoft how this could work [like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/multiple-hosted-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=route-subpath) but for this exact topic there is no tutorial or docs yet

Comment: I wasn't able to find an official document for adding subpath hosting in a Blazor web app. maybe this is because it's in preview, my idea is that we'd use .Net 7 temporarily.

Comment: could you pls have a few description about your ultimate goal for this requirement?

Comment: Sure, the big picture: we have a modular monolith which loads the modules dynmically via AssemblyLoadContextes (to speparte them). The host creates subroutes for each module and provides the corresponding IEndpointRouteBuilder to the module
https://<host>:<port>/<moduleRoute>/api/...
https://<host>:<port>/<moduleRoute>/app/...
there a module can register its APIs and/or its WebApp
The APIs work fine incl. OpenApiDoc via swagger.
The App part wich i try to register with GroupRouteBuilder.MapRazorComponents<MyApp>() shows the described behaviour

Comment: sorry and I'm afraid we don't have such out-of-box feature right now... let's see if there's someone else has ideas on it...

Comment: A workaround for your component routing, add @attribute [Route("/mySubPath")] in your Index component, add attribute [Route("/mySubPath/weather")] in your weather component

Comment: Seems it lacks a route template so that the embeded in file and the route component coun't be loaded